# Prove a student participates in all 2009 available courses.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In a university there are available 2009 courses in total. Each course has 45 enrolled students. Between every 2 courses there is exactly one student who was enrolled in both. Prove that there is a student who has enrolled in all of the courses.

I tried building a hypergraph where the courses are nodes and the students edges but this did not bring much. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the source of the problem?

Comment: The edges should be connected by the students that are common to the two classes.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @MishaLavrov i got it from lectures

Comment: @IanJ I am not sure what the representation of the data structure should be. However what is meant is that between any two courses a single common enrolled student exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume not. Then, we claim that a student can be in at most $45$ courses.

Proof: Take a student $S$ and a course $C$ such that $S$ is not in the course $C$. Let $E$ be the set of courses which contain $S$. Now, for every $E_i$ in $E$, we have $E_i \cap C$ contains exactly one student $e_i$. Note that these students are all distinct. So, if $\lvert E \rvert > 45$, then we would have a contradiction since $C$ contains $45$ students.

Now, let $C$ be a course. Find $n$ courses with at least $1$ student from $C$ ($C$ is not among these). By claim, we know that $n \leq 45 \cdot 44 < 2008$. So, there is a course which does not intersect with $C$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: "Note that all these students are distinct."  Why is that?

Comment: @saulspatz If not then those courses would both contain that student and $S$.